# pyspark filtering column values using endswith

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

Hi I'm trying to filter some values of a column in a table using a function "endswith".
The table looks like this

| itemName | itemValue |
| --- | --- |
| hp1_model1_min | 1 |
| hp1_model2_min | 1 |
| hp1_model3_min | 1 |
| hp1_model2_max | 1 |
| hp1_model3_max | 1 |
| hp1_model2_max | 1 |
| hp1_model4_min | 1 |
| hp1_model1_pressure | 1 |
| hp1_model2_pressure | 1 |

I want to filter values with names ending with "min" and "pressure"

when I'm using

```
table.filter(itemName.endswith("min"))
```

I get a table  like this

| itemName | itemValue |
| --- | --- |
| hp1_model1_min | row |
| hp1_model2_min | row |
| hp1_model3_min | Another header |
| hp1_model4_min | Another header |

but when I'm running this command which has 'or' condition

```
table.itemName.filter((table.itemName == itemName.endswith("min")) | (table.itemName == itemName.endswith("pressure"))
```

I get no result..

How can I get an outout like this below using pyspark

| itemName | itemValue |
| --- | --- |
| hp1_model1_min | 1 |
| hp1_model2_min | 1 |
| hp1_model3_min | 1 |
| hp1_model4_min | 1 |
| hp1_model1_pressure | 1 |
| hp1_model2_pressure | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to compare in **`filter`** as filter will result only the `true` value to output.

**Example:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('hp1_model1_min',1),('hp1_model1_pressure',1),('hp1_model3_max',1)],['itemName','itemValue'])
df.filter((col("itemname").endswith('min')) | (col("itemname").endswith('pressure'))).show(10,False)
#+-------------------+---------+
#|itemName           |itemValue|
#+-------------------+---------+
#|hp1_model1_min     |1        |
#|hp1_model1_pressure|1        |
#+-------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using below pyspark code to get desired results. Please note, `df` here hold your data in dataframe.

```
df.filter(df.itemName.contains('min') | df.itemName.contains('pressure')).show()
```